# Custom UITableCell and UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell and assigned it to a custom class.

The custom cell has two labels and one uitextfield in it.  Everything works great, but I need to be able to edit the text field with a date picker.  I can't seem to figure out how to make the textfield's inputview the date picker?  I can do it fine in a regular cell, but can't find a way to access it in my custom cell?

```
NSDate *eventDt= [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:[self trialDate] options:0];
    // NSLog(@"EVENT DATE: %@", eventDt);
    NSDateFormatter* dateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateF setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
    [dateF setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSString *eventDtforDisplay = [dateF stringFromDate:eventDt];
    resultscell.labelEventDesc.numberOfLines=0;
    [resultscell.labelEventDesc sizeToFit];
    [resultscell.labelEventDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eventDtforDisplay]];

this is my problem----> [resultscell.textEventDate.inputView = [self datePicker];

    [resultscell.textEventDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",eventDtforDisplay]];
     return resultscell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In custom cell you can do this very well in the **constructor** (init method) of the cell as **parameter**, or create a **setter method**. so you don't have to touch the `UITextField` in the parent class, but only handle the `inputView` in the cells setter method.

Seems also like handling with **delegates** and **protocols** could be usefull here. If you don't know how, here a small example: [Creating uitableview forms with uitextfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647941/creating-uitableview-forms-with-uitextfields/17648191#17648191)